# Why does the bell character work differently in RGui, Rstudio, and command line?

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I'm curious as to why `alarm` doesn't seem to work consistently or as advertised (Windows 7).

The `alarm` function is supposed to "an audible or visual signal to the user", but just prints two newlines to stdout with no sound when I run it in Rstudio. The documentation for the `alarm` function says `alarm() works by sending a "\a" character to the console`.

Now, I know the bell character doesn't work on every OS these days, but it works just fine on Windows 7: typing `^G` and `echo ^G` at the command prompt both produce the same system beep (and same goes for Powershell and `os.system("echo \a")` in python, for what it's worth). But running `cat("\a")` in Rstudio's R terminal produces the same result of two line breaks with no sound, as does `system("echo \a")`. Meanwhile, running all three of these commands (`alarm()`, `cat("\a")`, `system("echo \a")`) from the RGui console produces a sound - but it's a different sound than the one I get from the command line!

Since `echo("A")` sends a character to the R terminal stdout, I thought that perhaps this had to do with Rstudio's default stdout. But running `stdout()` in RGui and RStudio's terminal gave me the same result, so there's got to be at least something else going on to account for the difference.

```
stdout()
##description       class        mode        text      opened    can read   can write 
##   "stdout"  "terminal"         "w"      "text"    "opened"        "no"       "yes"
```

Comment: Neither RGui nor RStudio use a Windows console window, so there's no particular reason to expect them to respond to ^G in the same way it does.